# JFileChooser remote view

Tags: java, swing, file-io, filesystems, jfilechooser

I've been implementing a `JFileChooser` as a view for remote file system. When `getFiles()` is called from the `FileSystemView` I send request to the remote system with the directory location data.

Then asynchronously I receive back packet containing all files in the directory I am browsing, after that I am setting the files ready for updating view(so that next time `getFiles()` is called it will return the received array of files) but the problem is that I don't know how to update the `JFileChoosers` view.

I've tried

```
fileChooser.updateUI();
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-31" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.setDirectorySelected(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$Handler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.moveLeadSelectionIndex(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.FilePane.clearSelection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.FilePane.doFilterChanged(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.FilePane.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setFileFilter(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI(Unknown Source)
    at com.ruuhkis.remoteserver.ui.RemoteView.updateFiles(RemoteView.java:252)
    at com.ruuhkis.remoteserver.ui.RemoteApplication.onFileListReceived(RemoteApplication.java:122)
    at com.ruuhkis.remoteserver.packets.impl.FileListPacket.handlePacket(FileListPacket.java:32)
    at com.ruuhkis.remoteserver.packets.PacketHandler$1.run(PacketHandler.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

when I am on the directory and I know it has received new file list and I press f5 it will show the new files it just loaded, how can I make it so I don't have to press f5? Also by pressing f5 it causes the system to reload the pre existing data for the directory.

current code is basically:

```
    view = new FileSystemView() {

        int c;

        @Override
        public File[] getFiles(File dir, boolean useFileHiding) {

            if(!auto) {
                PacketBuilder builder = new PacketBuilder(OpCodes.FILE_LIST_REQUEST_PACKET.getOpCode());
                root = dir.getAbsolutePath();
                builder.writeString(dir.getAbsolutePath());
                builder.write(RemoteView.this.remote.getChannel());
            }
            auto = false;



            if(dirContent == null)
                return new File[]{new File((c++) + ".txt")};
            else
                return dirContent;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isTraversable(File arg0) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public File createNewFolder(File arg0) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };
```

c was basically just for testing so I can see if the system gets refreshed

when I receive the file list I do this:

```
public void updateFiles(String list) {
    String[] parts = list.split("" + ((char)10));
    File[] files = new File[parts.length];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < parts.length; i++) {
        files[i] = new File(root + File.separatorChar + parts[i]);

    }



    dirContent = files;

    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(root));

    fileChooser.updateUI();

    auto = true;

}
```

Comment: `pool-1-thread-31` does not sounds like the Event Dispatch Thread. Swing is not thread safe, so you shouldn't access the file chooser from another thread then the EDT

Comment: See also [`FileBrowser`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692).

Comment: @trashgod thats a beauty, I'll take a look at the code for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing other JFileChooser projects I found method

```
fileChooser.rescanCurrentDirectory();
```

which seems to update file system view..

everytime I ask a question I find answer shortly after :/

Comment: *"everytime I ask a question I find answer shortly after :/"*  Seems a close corollary of searching for something for months, then the moment you buy a replacement, the lost item appears as if by magic.  Look on the bright side, at least you did not have to buy anything in this case.  ;)

Comment: Good point you made there! :) Hopefully this will at least help someone else stumbling with the same problem.

Comment: I suspected you'd come up with more reasons once you had time to think it over.  :)

Answer (score 3):

- don't to call `fileChooser.updateUI();` this is for apply custom UI or to change methods from Look and Feel
- I think that better could be to use [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html),  or [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) as `FileSystemView`, then to create new [File, Folder e.i. programatically](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Catalog0180__File.htm)
- [examples here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm)

Comment: How could I use JList or JTree inside a JFileChooser?

Comment: not to use (JFileChooser contains JTable) instead of, and there are [one of great project by @Andrew Thompson](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4451/6673)

Comment: Good point, I probably have to try even though I like the UI of JFileChooser.

Comment: is probably easiest of ways, any re_loading of FileSystem you can to redirect to the SwingWorker or Runnable#Thread with lazily timing and processor impact, basically JList is proper of ways, but JTree is for most structured output...